# When Bitamp rotated it coordinates are also changing, so how to handle that

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation

Here am creating a image break puzzle game, in that I break image in to no of bitmap arrays and shuffled those bitmap arrays as well as rotated to `90`,`180`,`270`,`360` degrees.

Successful place in the grid view. Now I applied listeners on the view in the grid view, like Drag and Drop listeners, those also working fine for me. Now my question is, if i drag and drop the view in the grid view it need to shift their bitmap location for example A to B or B to A or A to c.

Here I can shifted non rotated bitmaps but if the bitmap is in 90 degrees or 180 degrees I can't shift, for example I have 6 bitmap arrays like `A,B,C,D,E,F` shuffled and rotated bitmap into certain degrees, now observe A=90 degrees, B=180 degrees, C=0 degrees,D=90 degrees, E=0 degrees, F= 0 degrees. Now i can shift 0 degrees bitmaps successfully and remaining i can't. I found some issue when I touch on bitmap with 0 degrees i can get coordinates like (60 , 186), then if i rotated the same bitmap to 90 degrees and then apply touch on the bitmap it gives coordinates like (260, 186).

So then how to cross change those bitmaps which are in different position. Help form this. Thank you.